# Best approach when writing unit tests and using for-loops?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

So I have a dilema with what is the best approach in this scenario.
I am writing a Unit Test which looks something like this:

```
void testCorrectAxeParse() 
{
  // Arrange
  InputData in = m_inputData;
  Parser p = m_Parser;
  in.setAxe(idata::Axes::AX_LEFT);

  // Act
  OutData out = p.parse(in);

  // Assert
  AssertEquals(in.getAxe(), out.getAxe());
}
```

Now I have 4 values in the `idata::Axes` array.

Is it ok to write a `for each` statement in order to test every value or should I write 4 tests, one for each value in the enum?

I have read online that UT should be as small as possible, and I don't know if adding for loops is ok.

Comment: What test framework are you using?

Comment: CXX framework for c++

Comment: common sense is more important than conventions. Can the individual array elements "fail" ? And more importantly, if an individual element fails, does this convey any useful information, does it matter which element was wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How best to compare two arrays in C++ with unit tests to verify they match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241902/how-best-to-compare-two-arrays-in-c-with-unit-tests-to-verify-they-match)